# Insert Element without Rewriting Existing Element in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
Array ( [0] => application [1] => modules [2] => Ride [3] => externals [4] => images [5] => uploads [6] => profile [7] => 116 [8] => 13006678321287904362.jpg )
```

How can I insert an item to the existing array with out overwriting the existing element in specified index

Consider I would like to create as follows

```
Array ( [0] => application [1] => modules [2] => Ride [3] => externals [4] => images [5] => uploads [6] => profile [7] => 116 [8] => model [9] => 13006678321287904362.jpg )
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elucidate on array_splice:

```
array_splice($array, $position, 0, $insert);
```

Where $array is the current array, $position is where you want to add the new item and $insert is the item to add (can be a new array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), I don't know if a better solution does exist.

Comment: I think you are right, he wants to insert new item in the middle of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if you want to add it to the end of the array

`<?php
$array[] = $var;
?>`